# Hiding legend box in QGIS map composer

Tags: qgis, print-composer, atlas

I'm generating an atlas in QGIS and adjusting it to only show the legend when the items are inside the current atlas feature. The problem is that when the items are not inside the atlas features it still appears as a small white box that corresponds to the background of the legend. I don't want to set the background to transparent as I have a satellite image underneath and it would be difficult to read the legend.

Is it possible to make the legend box completely disappear when my items are not in the atlas feature?

Comment: If you go to Rendering options in the Legend item properties, you could set the transparency based on a python function that counts the number of items in the legend. I'm not sure of another way sorry.